# How to change screen size cocos2dx win32 project

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2010, cocos2d-x

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and cocos2dx 2.2.3 for an iPad game project. Whenever I run my project, the screen size is of an iPhone (480 x 320). I want to test my application for different screen sizes.

How can I change screen size of my project when it is being ran from my computer so that its resolution matches an iPad?

Comment: If you mean the iOS Simulator from Apple provided with Xcode, then no. That Simulator is for OS X only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not install iPad emulator on Windows, if you want to test your app on Windows with different devices resolutions then you have to change `EGLView` frame size. You can change it in `main.cpp`

for ipad-normal : `eglView->setFrameSize(1024, 768);`

for ipad-retina : `eglView->setFrameSize(2048, 1536);`

If your game window size dosen't fit on your desktop then you can use `eglView->setFrameZoomFactor(0.5f)` to fit window in your monitor with scaled mode.